# How to set the number of keypoints(Descriptors) in SIFT algorithm in python using openCV 3.1?

Tags: python, sift, descriptor, opencv3.1

In opencv 3.0 and previous versions , the number of keypoints in SIFT can be limitize by using the code :

```
kp, des = cv2.SIFT(150).detectAndCompute(pic, None)
```

But as in opencv 3.1 , SIFT is moved to xfeatures2d so this function is giving error
How can i set the number of keypoints in SIFT  opencv3.1

My code is :

```
def gen_sift_features(gray_img):
    sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
    kp, desc = sift.detectAndCompute(gray_img, None)
    return kp, desc
```

Comment: detectAndCompute has a parameter for this, nFeature, you can set this parameter

Answer (score 1):

You can use nfeatures parameter as:

```
sift = cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create(nfeatures=150)
```

It is the number of best features to retain. The source:

```
help(cv.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create)
```

> SIFT_create(...)
>
> SIFT_create([, nfeatures[, nOctaveLayers[, contrastThreshold[, edgeThreshold[, sigma]]]]]) -> retval
>
> > .   @param nfeatures The number of best features to retain. The features are ranked by their scores
> >
> > .   (measured in SIFT algorithm as the local contrast)